# PySpark: Create New Column And Give similar value for each row with similar values of Other Columns

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

Imagine having the following spark dataframe

```
+---+----+----+
| Id|A_rk|B_rk|
+---+----+----+
|  a|   5|   4|
|  b|   7|   7|
|  c|   5|   4|
|  d|   1|   0|
+---+----+----+
```

I want to create a column called `Pair` that takes the value of `B_rk` if two rows have the same values for `A_rk` and `B_rk` and the value of 0 if there is no match. The result would be:

```
+---+----+----+----+
| Id|A_rk|B_rk|Pair|
+---+----+----+----+
|  a|   5|   4|   4|
|  b|   7|   7|   0|
|  c|   5|   4|   4|
|  d|   1|   0|   0|
+---+----+----+----+
```

I had a successful attempt with pandas using for loops. But I want to use spark for better performance.

Comment: You probably can get a better performance with pandas, too if your current attempt is using for loop.  You can still consider the Pyspark but it can be an overkill depends on your data size. What is the size of your data?  and could you share your current pandas code?

Comment: @emma This is just a toy data for the question. My actual data is quite big with 1.4 million rows. My pandas implementation takes many hours!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.4 million rows is still fine with `pandas`.

```py
data = [(randint(0, 1000000), randint(0, 100000)) for _ in range(1400000)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A_rk', 'B_rk'])

df['cnt'] = df.groupby(['A_rk', 'B_rk']).transform('size')
df.loc[df.cnt > 1, 'Pair'] = df.B_rk. # or df.cnt == 2 if you only count pair (2 rows exact).
df['Pair'] = df.Pair.fillna(0).astype(int)
```

I just ran this with 1.4 million rows and ran in less than a second.

```
389 ms ± 4.77 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Pyspark solution:

```py
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
w = Window.partitionBy('A_rk', 'B_rk')
df = (df.withColumn('cnt', F.count('A_rk').over(w))
      .withColumn('Pair', F.when(F.col('cnt') > 1, F.col('B_rk')).otherwise(F.lit(0))))
```

Comment: I can add Pyspark solution if you are still interested in.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would love to see the Pyspark solution as well if thta's possible. Because the goal would be to then run this on an even bigger data

Comment: I added the Pyspark solution.

Comment: In your pandas solution, shouldn't you specify the column which you want to transform? Otherwise you get a TypeError

Comment: i only have those 2 columns in the example, so this code won't get an error.  but if you have more columns, you are right you need to specify.